# How to show all images in configurable product before user has selected an option

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-images, swatches

It is very comfortable to the user navigate between all images product before select an option, but its confusing show all images when user has an option selected.

I'm looking for a way to show all thumbnails images **when the user has no option selected yet**.
It means: Show all simple product's images in gallery and possibility to view them before the user select an option in swatch, but when user select it, shows the simple product image (default behavior*)
*The default behavior is show the configurable product image and the simple product image.

P.S.:
Show all products images even when a option is selected is not the point of this question

How can I achieve it?